# How can I send data to multiple channels at once? (laravel, broadcasting)

Tags: laravel, websocket, redis, queue, laravel-echo

I have one event for broadcasting, there is channel for subscription on client side:

```
/**
* Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
*
* @return PrivateChannel
*/
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel("user.{$this->userId}");
}
```

How can I send data to multiple channels at once (on user.1, user.2, user.3 ...)?

**Refinement, to specific users, not to everyone who has subscribed to the room.**

Answer (score 9):

**I have found solution.**

```
/**
* Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
*
* @return PrivateChannel|array
*/
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return [
        new PrivateChannel("user.{$this->userId}"),
        new PrivateChannel("user.90"),
        new PrivateChannel("user.group.some_group"),
    ];
}
```